# Using string inside a View ... Asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have code like this:

```
@foreach (var query in ViewBag.listBestPlaces)
{
     int i =1;


     string aux1 = i.ToString;

//code
}
```

I am being unable to do so.... I am getting an error in the line 
 string aux1 = i.ToString;...
I already tried  string aux1 = (@i).ToString and didnt work....

EDIT: sorry to disturb, i forgot to put ToString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 string aux1 = i.ToString();
```

ToString is a method and as such it needs to be called with the braces.